# Store and retrieve private key in database

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, x509certificate2

I'm having difficulty loading an `X509Certificate2` from XML, using the `FromXmlString` method.  The exception I'm getting is `m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle.`

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException occurred
  HResult=-2146233296
  Message=m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_HasPrivateKey()
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
...
```

To create the XML, I'm loading the `.pfx` file and using `ToXmlString`;

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(
    @"D:\public_privatekey.pfx",
    (string)null,
    X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable
    );

var exportedPrivate = certificate.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);
```

This generate XML which starts like this...

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>y0iuejYHYajI...
```

To recreate the certificate, I'm using...

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2();
certificate.PrivateKey.FromXmlString(xml);
```

Where `xml` is a string containing the XML content.

The exception is thrown on the `FromXmlString` call.

I'm new to using certificates, but my best guess is that the `.pfx` contains both public and private keys, and possibly some other important data, and that I need all of that in order to have a valid X509 certificate.

However I couldn't find `ToXmlString` and `FromXmlString` on the `X509Certificate2` directly.  How should I do this?  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It will be easier to put whole .pfx file as binary column in SQL.

Comment: *"I'm having difficulty loading an X509Certificate2 from XML, using the FromXmlString method"* I didn't know `X509Certificate2` has `FromXmlString` method, which version of .net are you using?

Comment: `certificate.PrivateKey` wouldn't exist until you actually load a certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An X.509 certificate is described in a structured binary format called ASN.1/DER encoding. ASN.1 is a language to describe the contents of the certificate and DER is the encoding of the contents that comply with that ASN.1 structure.

Encoding your in-memory certificate separately from the private key can be done using the [`Export`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxz81eb9(v=vs.110).aspx) method using the content type `X509ContentType.Cert`. You can also export the certificate and private key back into a "pfx" by specifying `Pfx` or `Pkcs12`. If you require XML then you can encode the byte array result using base 64. You can then store it into an XML CDATA element.

---

Usually a private key is also stored in a binary PKCS#8 container format, also defined using ASN.1 / DER. Microsoft has however chosen to store the key into a Microsoft-proprietary XML format by default.

Comment: `is compatible with absolutely nothing on the market` -- it is well compatible with Microsoft software.

Comment: Thanks Maarten, the `Export` and `Import` methods were what I was overlooking.  I assumed there would be Xml functions for the certificate as there are for the private key, but with BASE64 encoding it worked like a charm.

Comment: Writing all the fields of a certificate to XML would be a pretty huge undertaking. There is a standardized method called XER, but that isn't used much (it simply saves the data fields specified using ASN.1 to XER - the XML encoding rules). However, since the signature over the certificate has been calculated over the DER encoding you would have to convert everything back to DER before verifying the signature :) So no, saving the certificate to XML is not a good idea; base 64 is used where required.